# Why my Google Compute Engine have a SLOW response time

Tags: google-compute-engine

I ran

```
ab -c 10 -n 1000 "MY_SITE_URL_HERE"
```

to test my server's response time, and it returns the longest request is 4000ms, which is unacceptable.

How can I diagnose the issue? Is it a software issue or hardware issue?

and How can I improve the server performance and reduce the server response time?

> FYI:
>
> My site uses Apache2.4.6 + PHP7 + MYSQL
>
> and using
>
> Google Compute Engine(1 vCPU, 1.7 GBram, Disk size 10GB) for the VM,
>
> Cloud SQL(D1, 1st gen, 250GB)

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue! Did you find a solution?

Comment: same here, did you find a solution? in my case I think it is the shared CPU